# Getting Memory limit error in chart generation

Tags: google-earth-engine, google-earth-engine-javascript-api, geemap

I'm trying to generate chart for SPI-12 for 16 days using CDR Dataset but I'm facing memory limit error. My code where I'm facing problem is given as:

```
//Plot SPI-16-Day Chart
var spiChart16Days = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  Final16DayCollection, //Image collection to be used
  RoiWithLabels, //Region that will be observed in Chart
  ee.Reducer.mean(), //Reducer type
  'SPI_16Days', //Band to be used
  resolution, //Scale in meter
  'system:time_start', 
  'labelSpi16' //label
  ).setOptions({
    title: 'SPI '+days+'-Day Time Series',
    vAxis: {title: 'SPI'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Year'},
    //legend: {position: 'none'},
});
print(days+'-days SPI chart based on mean values within AOI:',spiChart16Days);
```

and the link for script is:
https://code.earthengine.google.com/e9249c7471e0aabdf334bdd18a362f7c

Answer (score 0):

As your image collection only have 501 images, I think that the issue is in the feature collection named as ROI (not available for me). So, I assumed as your ROI a relatively large area in Pakistan with a relatively few quantity of vertices. It is included in complete [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/99cecca453d20fe613c3d3c97c505765) that it looks as follows:

```
var AOI = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[63.72370110579234, 25.730105677355056],
          [66.22858391829233, 26.085862887852784],
          [67.89850579329233, 24.856003679130257],
          [69.74420891829233, 25.01539878913604],
          [68.68952141829233, 26.950931764425828],
          [70.18366204329233, 28.468177179410898],
          [71.50202141829233, 28.429538586517047],
          [75.89655266829233, 33.586680142500754],
          [77.69831048079233, 33.586680142500754],
          [77.87409173079233, 34.786258846084124],
          [74.49030266829233, 36.4650015510311],
          [72.29303704329233, 36.18175293206798],
          [72.51276360579233, 35.18231013923115],
          [67.59088860579233, 29.773406235568583],
          [63.32819329329234, 28.69971170557911]]]);

/*var AOI = ee.Geometry.Polygon(
        [[[67.12612396367388, 30.945815660948572],
          [67.12612396367388, 25.687327572466582],
          [69.27944427617388, 25.687327572466582],
          [69.27944427617388, 30.945815660948572]]], null, false);
*/

// PERSIAN CDR SPI

var SPImonthlyVis = {"opacity":1,"bands":["SPI"],"min":-4,"max":4,"palette":["d53e4f","fc8d59","fee08b","ffffbf","e6f598","99d594","3288bd"]};

//var AOI = ee.FeatureCollection("users/sunny912398/Pakistan");

var CDR = ee.ImageCollection('NOAA/PERSIANN-CDR');

var firstImage = ee.Date('1983-01-01');
var latestImage = ee.Date('2020-12-31');
var showInteractiveChart = true;
//                                 SET TIME FRAME FOR EXPORT

var exportdata = true; //set to 'true' if you wish to export images
var startDateForDownload = '1983-01-01';
var endDateForDownload = '1983-12-31';


//=====================================================================================================
//                                     SET RESOLUTION
var resolution = 5550;

//=====================================================================================================
//                            SET TIME SCALE INFORMATION FOR SPI
var firstImage = ee.Date('1985-01-01');
var latestImage = ee.Date('2020-12-31');
var timestep = '12';

//=====================================================================================================
//                            SET TIME SHIFT FOR MODIS RELATED SPI
var shift = '0';
var days = '16';

var showInteractiveChart = true;

//MONTHLY SPI
var thresholdMonths = ee.Number(12)

var timedif = (latestImage.difference(firstImage, 'month')).divide(ee.Number.parse(timestep));

var list = ee.List.sequence(0, timedif); 

//Map the dates (beginning with the latest image) of the months ends over the list, counting backwards in time
var timeListDate = list.map(function(month){
  var zero = ee.Number(0); //Is needed to substract month
  var delta = (zero.subtract(month)).multiply(ee.Number.parse(timestep)); //results in a negative counting in the list (from latest image backwards) in the steps provided by the user
  var latestDate = latestImage.advance(1, 'day');//Advance one day to include the latest image (starts counting at 00:00 o'clock)
  return latestDate.advance(delta, 'month');//returns a list of dates counted from latest date backwards
});
  
var sortedTimeList = timeListDate.sort();

var PrecipitationSum = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(timeListDate.map(function(monthly_sum){
  var startTime = ee.Date(monthly_sum).advance(ee.Number.parse(timestep).multiply(-1), 'month');
  var endTime = ee.Date(monthly_sum);
  var filteredCDR = CDR.filterDate(startTime, endTime);
  var clippedCDR = filteredCDR.map(function(clip){return clip.clip(AOI)});
  var imageAmount = clippedCDR.size();
  var summedCollection = clippedCDR
    .sum()
    .set({
      'Used_Images': imageAmount,
      'Start_Date': ee.Date(filteredCDR.first().get('system:time_start')),
      'End_Date': ee.Date(filteredCDR.limit(1, 'system:time_end', false).first().get('system:time_end')),
      'system:time_start': filteredCDR.first().get('system:time_start'), //Add start date to new image
      'system:time_end': filteredCDR.limit(1, 'system:time_end', false).first().get('system:time_end') //Add end date to new image
    });
  var time = ee.Date(summedCollection.get('system:time_end')).difference(ee.Date(summedCollection.get('system:time_start')), 'month').round();
  var summedImage = summedCollection.set({
    'Observed_Months': time
  });
return ee.Algorithms.If(
  time.gte(ee.Number.parse(timestep)), 
  summedImage);
}));

var summedCDRCollection = ee.ImageCollection(PrecipitationSum.copyProperties(CDR));

//If the SPI should be calculated for more then 12 months, a different approach has to be used.
//The following lines decide, which approach to use.
var SPI = ee.ImageCollection(ee.Algorithms.If(
  ee.Number.parse(timestep).gte(thresholdMonths), 
  SpiGreaterEqual12(), 
  SpiSmaller12()));

//If the SPI should be calculated for less than 12 months, the DOY information have to be used
//to find the correct images.
function SpiSmaller12 (){
    //Calculate Statistics
  var stats = summedCDRCollection.map(function(toStats){
    var startDOY  = ee.Date(toStats.get('system:time_start')).getRelative('day', 'year');
    var endDOY = ee.Date(toStats.get('system:time_end')).getRelative('day', 'year');
    var collectionForStats = summedCDRCollection
      .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(startDOY, endDOY, 'day_of_year'))
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev().combine(ee.Reducer.mean(), null, true));
    return toStats.addBands(collectionForStats);
  });
  
  
    //Calculate SPI
  var SPI1_11 = stats.map(function(toSPI){
    var bandForSPI = toSPI.select(['precipitation'], ['SPI']);
    var calc = toSPI.expression('(precipitation - mean) / stdDev',
    {
      precipitation: bandForSPI,
      mean: toSPI.select('precipitation_mean'),
      stdDev: toSPI.select('precipitation_stdDev')});
    return toSPI.addBands(calc);
  });
return SPI1_11;
}

function SpiGreaterEqual12 (){
    //Calculate Statistics
  var stats = summedCDRCollection.map(function(toStats){
    var collectionForStats = summedCDRCollection
      .reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev().combine(ee.Reducer.mean(), null, true));
    return toStats.addBands(collectionForStats);
  });
  
    //Calculate SPI
  var SPI12_n = stats.map(function(toSPI){
    var bandForSPI = toSPI.select(['precipitation'], ['SPI']);
    var calc = toSPI.expression('(precipitation - mean) / stdDev',
    {
      precipitation: bandForSPI,
      mean: toSPI.select('precipitation_mean'),
      stdDev: toSPI.select('precipitation_stdDev')});
    return toSPI.addBands(calc);
  });
return SPI12_n;
}

//16-DAY SPI
//SPI from CDR date in MODIS 16-days timeline
//Create a list with MODIS start Dates for each 16-day period
var listMillis = MODIS.aggregate_array('system:time_start');

//Turns the millis format of the list into a normal date format. A user provided shift in time will be reognised here as well
var listDates = listMillis.map(function(getDate){
  return ee.Date(getDate).advance(ee.Number.parse(shift), 'day');
});


//Sum up the CDR precipitation data for each 16 day MODIS interval
var precipitation16Days = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(listDates.map(function(summarize_16Days){
  var filterCDR = CDR.filterDate(ee.Date(summarize_16Days), ee.Date(summarize_16Days).advance(ee.Number.parse(days), 'day'));
  var clippedCDR = filterCDR.map(function(clip){return clip.clip(AOI)});
  var imageAmount = clippedCDR.size();
  return ee.Algorithms.If(
    imageAmount.gte(ee.Number.parse(days)), 
    clippedCDR
      .sum()
      .setMulti({
        'Used_Images': imageAmount,
        'system:time_start': filterCDR.first().get('system:time_start'),
        'Start_Date': ee.Date(filterCDR.first().get('system:time_start')),
        'system:time_end': filterCDR.limit(1, 'system:time_end', false).first().get('system:time_end'),
        'End_Date': ee.Date(filterCDR.limit(1, 'system:time_end', false).first().get('system:time_end'))
      }));
}));

//Create a list with MODIS start Dates for each 16-day period
var listMillis = MODIS.aggregate_array('system:time_start');

//Turns the millis format of the list into a normal date format. A user provided shift in time will be reognised here as well
var listDates = listMillis.map(function(getDate){
  return ee.Date(getDate).advance(ee.Number.parse(shift), 'day');
});


//Sum up the CDR precipitation data for each 16 day MODIS interval
var precipitation16Days = ee.ImageCollection.fromImages(listDates.map(function(summarize_16Days){
  var filterCDR = CDR.filterDate(ee.Date(summarize_16Days), ee.Date(summarize_16Days).advance(ee.Number.parse(days), 'day'));
  var clippedCDR = filterCDR.map(function(clip){return clip.clip(AOI)});
  var imageAmount = clippedCDR.size();
  return ee.Algorithms.If(
    imageAmount.gte(ee.Number.parse(days)), 
    clippedCDR
      .sum()
      .setMulti({
        'Used_Images': imageAmount,
        'system:time_start': filterCDR.first().get('system:time_start'),
        'Start_Date': ee.Date(filterCDR.first().get('system:time_start')),
        'system:time_end': filterCDR.limit(1, 'system:time_end', false).first().get('system:time_end'),
        'End_Date': ee.Date(filterCDR.limit(1, 'system:time_end', false).first().get('system:time_end'))
      }));
}));


//Calculate statistics for each image
var stats16DayCollection = precipitation16Days.map(function(stats){
  var startDOY = ee.Date(stats.get('system:time_start')).getRelative('day', 'year');
  var endDOY = ee.Date(stats.get('system:time_end')).getRelative('day', 'year');
    //Calculate number of images used for mean and stdev calculations
  var imageAmount = precipitation16Days.filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(startDOY, endDOY, 'day_of_year')).size();
  var collectionForStats = precipitation16Days
    .filter(ee.Filter.calendarRange(startDOY, endDOY, 'day_of_year'))
    .reduce(ee.Reducer.stdDev().combine(ee.Reducer.mean(), null, true));
  return stats.addBands(collectionForStats).setMulti({'Images_for_Stats': imageAmount});
});


//Calculate SPI
var Final16DayCollection = stats16DayCollection.map(function(toSPI16Days){
  var bandForSPI = toSPI16Days.select(['precipitation'], ['SPI_16Days']);
  var calc = toSPI16Days.expression('(precipitation - mean) / stdDev',
  {
    precipitation: bandForSPI,
    mean: toSPI16Days.select('precipitation_mean'),
    stdDev: toSPI16Days.select('precipitation_stdDev')});
  return toSPI16Days.addBands(calc);
});

var RoiWithLabels = ee.FeatureCollection(AOI).map(function(addLabels){
  var labelNames = addLabels
    .set('labelSpiMonth','SPI-'+timestep)
    .set('labelSpi16', 'SPI ('+days+' days)')
    .set('labelMonthlyPrecip', timestep+' Month(s) Precipitation Sum');
  return labelNames;
});

print(Final16DayCollection);

//Plot SPI-16-Day Chart
var spiChart16Days = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  Final16DayCollection, //Image collection to be used
  RoiWithLabels, //Region that will be observed in Chart
  ee.Reducer.mean(), //Reducer type
  'SPI_16Days', //Band to be used
  resolution, //Scale in meter
  'system:time_start', 
  'labelSpi16' //label
  ).setOptions({
    title: 'SPI '+days+'-Day Time Series',
    vAxis: {title: 'SPI'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Year'},
    //legend: {position: 'none'},
});
print(days+'-days SPI chart based on mean values within AOI:',spiChart16Days);

////////////////////

//Inspector Chart
// Create a panel to hold the chart.
if (showInteractiveChart === true){
  var inspectorPanel = ui.Panel({
    style:{
      width: '400px',
      position: 'bottom-right'
    }
  });
  Map.add(inspectorPanel);
  
  // Register a function to draw a chart when a user clicks on the map.
  Map.onClick(function(coords) {
  inspectorPanel.clear();
  var point = ee.FeatureCollection(ee.Geometry.Point(coords.lon, coords.lat)).map(function(addLabels){
    var labelNames = addLabels.set('labelSPI', 'SPI_16Days-'+timestep);
  return labelNames;
  });
  
    //Button to hide Panel once the chart is loaded
  var hideButton = ui.Button({
    label: 'X',
    onClick: function(){
      inspectorPanel.clear();
    },
    style:{
      color: 'red',
    }
  });
  inspectorPanel.add(hideButton);
  
    //Chart to display data history of clicked point
  var inspectorChart = ui.Chart.image.seriesByRegion(
  Final16DayCollection, 
  point, 
  ee.Reducer.mean(),
  'SPI_16Days', 
  resolution, //Scale in meter
  'system:time_start', 
  'labelSPI' //label
  ).setOptions({
    title: 'SPI_16Days-'+timestep+' Time Series (based on CDR)',
    vAxis: {title: 'SPI_16Days'},
    hAxis: {title: 'Year'},
    //legend: {position: 'none'},
    });
  inspectorChart.setOptions({title: 'SPI_16Days-'+timestep+' for requested pixel'});
  inspectorPanel.add(inspectorChart);
  });
}

//************************************************************************************************* 
//Create title
//Add Title
var title = ui.Label({
  value: 'Drought monitoring using the Standardized Precipitation Index (SPI)',
  style:{
  fontWeight: 'bold',
  fontSize: '18px'
  }});
title.style().set('position', 'top-center');
Map.add(title);

//************************************************************************************************* 
//Create legend

//Get Max and Min values from imports-section with one decimal 
var SPI16DayVis = {"opacity":1,"bands":["SPI_16Days"],"min":-4,"max":4,"palette":["d53e4f","fc8d59","fee08b","ffffbf","e6f598","99d594","3288bd"]};

var get16DayVisMax = Math.round(SPI16DayVis.max*10)/10;
var get16DayVisMin = Math.round(SPI16DayVis.min*10)/10;

var viz16Days = {min: get16DayVisMin, max:get16DayVisMax, palette:SPI16DayVis.palette};

//Add main panel which will contain smaller panels for each legend (SVI, EVI, Mean EVI)
    var mainPanel = ui.Panel({
      layout: ui.Panel.Layout.flow('horizontal'),
      style: {
        position: 'bottom-left',
        padding: '8px 15px'
      }
    });
//***************************************************
//****************************************************
//Add new panel for 16 Day SPI legend within the main Panel
        var Spi16Legend = ui.Panel({
          style: {
             //position: 'bottom-left',
             padding: '0 0'
           }
        });
        mainPanel.add(Spi16Legend);
         //Create a checkbox which will enable a toggle function to show the SVI legend
        var Spi16Checkbox = ui.Checkbox('Show '+days+'-Day SPI Legend', false);
          //Provide information what happens if the checkbox is checked or unchecked
        Spi16Checkbox.onChange(function(checked) {
          if (checked) { //if it is checked, fill the SVI legend panel with information
          //Create first line of legend title
            var Spi16LegendTitle = ui.Label({
              value: days+'-Day',
              style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '18px',
                margin: '0 auto',
                padding: '0 auto'
                }
            });
            
             // Add the title to the panel
            Spi16Legend.add(Spi16LegendTitle);
              //Create second line of title
            var Spi16LegendTitle2 = ui.Label({
              value: 'SPI',
              style: {
                fontWeight: 'bold',
                fontSize: '18px',
                margin: '0 auto',
                padding: '0 auto'
                }
            });
            
             // Add the title to the panel
            Spi16Legend.add(Spi16LegendTitle2);
            
            // create the legend image
            var Spi16Lon = ee.Image.pixelLonLat().select('latitude');
            var Spi16Gradient = Spi16Lon.multiply((viz16Days.max-viz16Days.min)/100.0).add(viz16Days.min);
            var Spi16LegendImage = Spi16Gradient.visualize(viz16Days);
            
            // create text on top of legend
            var spi16PanelMax = ui.Panel({
                widgets: [
                  ui.Label(viz16Days['max'])
                ],
                style: {
                  padding: '0 auto',
                  margin: '0 auto',
                  position: 'bottom-center'
                }
              });
            
            Spi16Legend.add(spi16PanelMax);
              
            // create thumbnail from the image
            var spi16Thumbnail = ui.Thumbnail({
              image: Spi16LegendImage, 
              params: {bbox:'0,0,10,100', dimensions:'10x150'},  
              style: {
                  padding: '0 auto',
                  margin: '0 auto',
                  position: 'bottom-center'
                }
            });
            
            // add the thumbnail to the legend
              Spi16Legend.add(spi16Thumbnail);
            
            // create text on top of legend
            var spi16PanelMin = ui.Panel({
                widgets: [
                  ui.Label(viz16Days['min'])
                ],
                style: {
                  padding: '0 auto',
                  margin: '0 auto',
                  position: 'bottom-center'
                }
                });
            
            Spi16Legend.add(spi16PanelMin);
      
      
        } else {
          Spi16Legend.clear()
          }
        });
        print(Spi16Checkbox);


Map.add(mainPanel);


//Add layers to map 
// print('The observed time period for the SPI-'+timestep+' begins on ', firstImage.format('YYYY-MM-dd'),'and ends on ', latestImage.format('YYYY-MM-dd'));

Map.centerObject(AOI,5); //Center map view to ROI
 
Map.addLayer(
  Final16DayCollection.limit(1, 'system:time_start', false).first(), 
{"opacity":1,"bands":["SPI_16Days"],"min":-1.0284844202494692,"max":-0.3506398903395315,"palette":["d53e4f","fc8d59","fee08b","ffffbf","e6f598","99d594","3288bd"]},
  'SPI '+days+' days from '+ee.Date(Final16DayCollection.limit(1, 'system:time_start', false).first().get('system:time_start')).format('YYYY-MM-dd').getInfo());

var batch = require('users/fitoprincipe/geetools:batch');

// if (exportdata===true){
// var ImageCollectionForExportMonthly = Final16DayCollection.select(['SPI_16Days']).filterDate(startDateForDownload, endDateForDownload);
// print('Selected images for SPI_16Days-'+timestep+' export',ImageCollectionForExportMonthly);

// batch.Download.ImageCollection.toDrive(ImageCollectionForExportMonthly, "SPI_ImageCollection",{
//   name: 'SPI_16Days-'+timestep+'_from_{system_date}',
//   scale: resolution,
//   region: AOI
// });
// }
```

After running it in GEE code editor, it was printed the chart and it was also added the corresponding image; as it can be observed in following picture. My suggestion is for simplifying your probably complicated geometry named as ROI. I hope this helps.

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much. It really helped.

Comment: can this chart be converted to Senslope and MK trend?